# How to implement an Image Slider that becomes full screen when clicked?

Tags: android, image, slider, fullscreen

How can I add an image slider that becomes full screen when clicked?
I would like to be able to preview the images in full screen mode and be able to share it or zoom it. What are some ways that I can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [lib](https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage) to zoom image and for sharing an image you can use share intent

```
Bitmap icon = mBitmap;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: and what about the slider becomes full screen when clicked? @Milan

Comment: create a full screen fragment and open it

Comment: can you give link or article for that ?